# struct look up table using string pointers issue

Tags: c

I have written the following code:

```
unsigned char *cPtr[] =
{
    "First",
    "Second",
    "Third"
};

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    char *lut;  /* or char lut[20]*/
}Grp_t;

const Grp_t Grp_st[]=
{
    { 0, cPtr[0] },
    { 1, cPtr[1] },
    { 2, cPtr[2] }
};
```

When I try to compile this code I got the following error:

**error: initializer element is not constant**

**error: (near initialization for 'Grp_st[0].lut[0]')**

But when I replace `*cPtr[]` by `cPtr[][16]` as

```
unsigned char cPtr[][16] =
{
    "First",
    "Second",
    "Third"
};
```

I am able to successfully compile the code.

Please can any one explain me the concept which I am missing here.

Comment: You can't do that in C. And when it compiles with `cPtr[][16]` you should get warnings and it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, what you mean when say that it can't be doing in C? Sometimes I got same problem and solve it by chain of declarations: `unsigned char c_ptr_0[] = "First"; unsigned char c_ptr_1[] = "Second"; unsigned char * c_ptr[] = { c_ptr_0, c_ptr_1 };` - so what can't be doing here?

Comment: @MichaelWalz, Could you please elaborate

Comment: @user1093152 see answer below.

Comment: @imbearr that's not quite the same thing, see answer below.

Comment: @user1093152 Please see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

It is the limitation of C.

*6.7.8.4 Initialization*:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
>   storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

And *6.6.9 Constant expressions*:

> An address constant is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue
>   designating an object of static storage duration, or a pointer to a
>   function designator; it shall be created explicitly using the unary &
>   operator or an integer constant cast to pointer type, or implicitly by
>   the use of an expression of array or function type. The
>   array-subscript [] and member-access . and -> operators, the address &
>   and indirection * unary operators, and pointer casts may be used in
>   the creation of an address constant, but the value of an object shall
>   not be accessed by use of these operators.

If you can change the code to make `Grp_st` not of static storage duration it compiles:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char *cPtr[] =
{
    "First",
    "Second",
    "Third"
};

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    const char *lut;
} Grp_t;


int main(void) {
    Grp_t Grp_st[]= {
    { 0, cPtr[0] },
    { 1, cPtr[1] },
    { 2, cPtr[2] }
    };
    return 0;
}
```

In the second case you managed to compile the code because you didn't access array element at given index, but only a pointer (in case of `char cPtr[][16]`, the `cPtr[0]` gives address of the first array of 16 characters and `cPtr[0]` decays to type `char *` in expression) - therefore you didn't violate the *6.6.9* rule.

Comment: *cPtr[] and cPtr[][16] what are the differences?

Comment: in second case you used a pointer and not accessed arrray value at given index, therefore you didn't violate the 6.6.9 rule

Comment: @user1093152 ... and it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: If I am using *cPtr[] then what does it mean cPtr[0] or cPtr[1].

If I am using cStr[][16], then what doest it mean cStr[0] or cStr[1].

Comment: @user1093152 I hope the explanation is now complete. You may also wish to check [this](https://ideone.com/s070U8) example.

Answer (score 1):

Initializer for a static object must be constant<sup>1</sup>.

Since you're trying to initialize a member of a static object, the member having the type pointer to char, you need an address constant<sup>2</sup>.

`cPtr[0]` is not an address constant because the value of the object `cPtr` is accessed while trying to create this address constant<sup>3</sup>.

On the other hand, `cStr[0]` doesn't access any value of the object `cStr`. The expression `cStr[0]` is identical to `&cStr[0][0]`, which clearly doesn't access the value, but only the address to that value.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.7.9 Initialization 4)
All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration
shall be constant expressions or string literals.

<sup>2</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.6 Constant expressions 9)
An address constant is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static
storage duration, or a pointer to a function designator; it shall be created explicitly using
the unary & operator or an integer constant cast to pointer type, or implicitly by the use of
an expression of array or function type. The array-subscript [] and member-access .
and -> operators, the address & and indirection * unary operators, and pointer casts may
be used in the creation of an address constant, but the value of an object shall not be
accessed by use of these operators.

<sup>3</sup> but the value of an object shall not be
accessed by use of these operators.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly a complement to @where_is_ftp's answer to add details on the difference between `*cPtr[]` and `cPtr[][16]`.

The former case is an array of pointers. In that case, the addresses `cPtr[0]`, `cPtr[1]`, `cPtr[2]` are un-related and are run-time values, the addresses of the pointed strings.

The latter is a 2D array. In that cases the addresses `cPtr[0]`, `cPtr[1]`, and `cPtr[2]` are addresses inside the 2D array specifically, `cPtr[1] == cPtr[0] + 16`, and the original strings have been copied into the 2D arrays as an array initialization. That's the reason why they are now constant values.